# Old use of the past perfect?

Tags: past-perfect

The verb tense (‘was come’), in this sentence by John Steinbeck, strikes me as odd. Is this common use in modern literary works to construct the past perfect? And is it correct?

‘All afternoon the wind sifted out of the black Welsh glens, crying notice that Winter **was come** sliding down over the world from the Pole;’
(*Cup of Gold*)

Comment: It sounds folksy. That's all. It is not past perfect. That would be: had come.